# Cannot store a complex object in memcached

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim

I'm working with Enyim.Caching the memcached client for C# the server is http://memcached.org on the last version of ubuntu

```
MemcachedClient mc = new MemcachedClient();
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
mc.Store(StoreMode.Set, "foo", xmlDocument);
object myXml= mc.Get("foo");
```

and myXml is null, why is there a way to Store my object.
The purpose : 
I'm trying to replace HttpCache in my code for Memcached but with HttpCache I can add complex object to the cache.

Here XmlDocument is an example but with a simple class it doesn't work too

Comment: what is the memcache build you use? I recommend you to use [this](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/memcached) on windows.

Comment: I working with http://memcached.org on ubuntu and Before I change all my server can you confirm me that with your solution I will be able to store complexe object?

Comment: `XmlDocument` does not appear to be binary `[Serializable]`. Use the string representation of the XML instead i.e. `xmlDocument.OuterXml`.

Comment: @chibacity however XmlDocument is not binary serialisable I tried with another custom class it doesn't work too, if I try with String or int... it work

Comment: @Christophe I know `XmlDocument` is not binary serializable, hence my comment. I suggested `string` becuase that is binary serializable. Your classes must support `[Serializable]` to work. I suggest string for this as you can convert back to `XmlDocument`. For serializing your custom class, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx.

Comment: @chibacity ok all right I arrive to serialize my object but how HTTPCache can cache XmlDocument if it is not serializable?

Comment: @Christophe The HTTPCache is in-process, therefore objects do not need to be transmitted over the network. Whereas Memcached is a server application, so you need to flatten your objects to bytes (i.e. serialize) for transmission to and from the server.

Comment: I'm ok with that but my objects are bytes in RAM so there are already binary "serialised" the idea is to retreive byte array in RAM to build a new instance of my class

Comment: @Christophe They are not binary serialized - serialized hints that they are a sequence of bytes. Your objects are in fact splattered all over the heap\memory, and joined up with pointers. For transmission over the network the object needs to be a byte[] array. Your object at runtime is not organized like this. It will also have pointers to data structures such as tables of type information, which may point to non-existent memory location if they were to come back later. Serialization is about flattening all of this, and removing memory references, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for classes to be used with Memcached, they need to support binary serialization, this allows objects to be converted to a flat byte data-representation and then transmitted to  and from the Memcached server.

In your example you use `XmlDocument`, which is not binary serializable. You can work around this by converting it to and from `string` which *is* binary serializable:

```
    MemcachedClient mc = new MemcachedClient();
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    mc.Store(StoreMode.Set, "foo", xmlDocument.OuterXml);
    string myXml = mc.Get("foo");
    XmlDocument xmlDocumentOut = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocumentOut.LoadXml(myXml);
```

For your own custom classes, you need to add the `[Serializable]` attribute and follow guidelines for binary serialization: [SerializableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).

Comment: I can't add the memory print of the XmlDocument? because, the idea is to avoid serialisation/deserialisation that cost proc time

Comment: @Christophe You cannot avoid serialization, as this is required so that your "object" can be transmitted to the Memcached server. The object graph needs to be converted to a flat byte oriented data stream. If you need to make this process more efficient, I would look at using protobuf.net which is much more efficient than .Net's binary serialization - faster and less bandwidth. You're still going to have problems with `XmlDocument` as it is not binary serializable. Create your own class and follow protobuf.net's guidelines.

Comment: @Christophe Protobuf.net is a very efficient **binary** serializer, json is **text**. Json is still less verbose than xml, but Protobuf is very quick and produces much smaller payloads.

Comment: Looks like memcached requires Serializable to be on custom classes being saved into the cache, thanks!